# Visual Studio Regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am fairly new to Regex and my problem always seems to be that my regex works in all online Regex testers but never in visual studio.

Here is my Regex:

```
    "void TestSerializableClass\\:\\:TestSerializableClassPreSerializationCallback\\(\\)\\s"
    "{\\s+USER_CODE_REGION\\(TestSerializableClass_PreSerializationCallback\\)\\s+"
    "//Write the PreSerialization code here\\s+USER_CODE_ENDREGION"
    "\\(TestSerializableClass_PreSerializationCallback\\)\\s+}";
```

I want it to find this:

```
void TestSerializableClass::TestSerializableClassPreSerializationCallback()
{
    USER_CODE_REGION(TestSerializableClass_PreSerializationCallback)
    //Write the PreSerialization code here
    USER_CODE_ENDREGION(TestSerializableClass_PreSerializationCallback)
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Invalid content of repeat range.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'ack\(\)\s{>>>HERE>>>\s+USER_CO'.
```

This is the regex that was working before I tried to port it into visual studio:

```
void TestSerializableClass::TestSerializableClassPreSerializationCallback\(\)\s{\s+USER_CODE_REGION\(TestSerializableClass_PreSerializationCallback\)\s+//Write the PreSerialization code here\s+USER_CODE_ENDREGION\(TestSerializableClass_PreSerializationCallback\)\s+}
```

Comment: You're trying to match C++ code with a regex?! Anyway, as a first step, massively reduce the size of the function that you're trying to match. Like, massively. Then build it up until it fails. Then you'll know the bit that fails. Debugging m8! :)

Comment: Yes, it is for a test case of a code generator. To make sure it is generating the correct functions.

Comment: Are you aware that there are different kinds of Regexp syntax? (And that Regexp are not able to properly process C++ code?)

Comment: Are you properly escaping backslashes twice? You need to escape them in the code, but also in the expression that's looking for escaped backslashes (e.g. to find literal \ you need \\\\\)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost (and C++11) have a problem with stand alone literal quantifier range operators `{}`.
So all you have to do is escape them.

I did this in a couple button clicks with [RegexFormat 5](http://www.regexformat.com).
It has a built-in boost regex tester that is free, if you want to format you have to get a key.
Parses, makes c++ strings, formats/compresses/comments regex, and tests them too ..
Handy tool, this is the way to go if you are doing a lot of regex development for C++.

```
"(?x)                                                                                                \n"
"     void\\ TestSerializableClass\\:\\:TestSerializableClassPreSerializationCallback\\(\\) \\s      \n"
"     \\{ \\s+                                                                                       \n"
"     USER_CODE_REGION\\(TestSerializableClass_PreSerializationCallback\\) \\s+                      \n"
"     //Write\\ the\\ PreSerialization\\ code\\ here \\s+                                            \n"
"     USER_CODE_ENDREGION\\(TestSerializableClass_PreSerializationCallback\\) \\s+                   \n"
"     \\}                                                                                            \n"
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 263 ) 
void TestSerializableClass::TestSerializableClassPreSerializationCallback()
{
    USER_CODE_REGION(TestSerializableClass_PreSerializationCallback)
    //Write the PreSerialization code here
    USER_CODE_ENDREGION(TestSerializableClass_PreSerializationCallback)
}
```